# How to update the properties of react component using static method?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I have a component like below

```
interface JoPanelViewProps {
    joSelection?: number;    
}

interface JourneyPanelViewState {
    dateInput?: string;
    jos?: Array<JoModel>;
}

function mapStateToProps(state: TStoreState, ownProps: JoPanelViewProps): JoPanelViewProps {
    const { joSelection } = state;

    return { joSelection };
}

@connect(mapStateToProps, null, null, { pure: true })
class JoPanelView extends React.Component<JoPanelViewProps, JoPanelViewState>{

    private jos: JoModel;

    constructor(props: JoPanelViewProps, context?: any) {
        super(props, context);
        this.state = {
            dateInput:  moment().format('DD/MM/YYYY')
        }
        this.fetchJos(this.props.joSelection);
    }

    private fetchJos(joId:number):void{
        // updates jos to state to trigger render
    }    

}
```

How to update joId to properties of component from outside of this class using the static member function? or Is there a way i can do that?